# How to change the Git account used in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: git, continuous-delivery

I am new to Bluemix. I use Git to store the code developed in my Bluemix account. Until now I used my personal account(user/pwd). Now i want to use a different repository which has a different username and password combination. How can I achieve this?
When I click on the enable button Bluemix does not ask me for a repository authentication. And from my previous experience in such case it will link it to my personal repository which is not intended.
Can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to associate a different GitHub account with your Bluemix id, you will need to revoke the token that was granted under your first GitHub account.  Navigate to https://github.com/settings/applications as your first GitHub user, find the entry for Bluemix, and click "Revoke".

The next time you try to add a new GitHub repository in Bluemix, you will be prompted to authorize with GitHub again.  Make sure you're logged in to GitHub under the new id and authorize Bluemix to access the new GitHub account.  This will allow you to create new repositories under the new GitHub account or link to repositories the new GitHub account has access to.